# Rule precedence & parse tree

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Given a grammar like this

```
test: x;

x  : x '+' x
   | x '*' x
   | INT
   ;

INT: [0-9]+
```

(The switched up precedence is on purpose)

The Input is the following: 6+7*8*9

When I look at the Parse Tree it looks like it is calculated (((6+7)*8)*9).

What I don't understand is how the parse tree is constructed.
It seems to me that this is how it was constructed:

```
                       Rules applied

test                   test: x
x                      x '*' x
(x * x)                x '*' x
((x * x) * x)          x '+' x
(((x + x) * x) * x)
```

But why doesn't it try to to apply the `x  : x '+' x` first. It is the first rule alternative and the input tokens would match. But if that would be the case,the parse tree would look like this:

```
                       Rules applied

test                   test: x
x                      x '+' x
(x + x)                x '*' x
(x + (x * x))          x '*' x
(x + (x * (x * x)))
```

I read that it tries to match first alternative first but that does not seem to be the case here. What is the reason? And what does precedence actually mean?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the last question: precedence (in this context) is the term to describe in which order sub expressions have to be evaluated. There are pretty common precedence rules like: `*` and `/` have the same precedence and are evaluated left to right, but before any `+` or `-` sub expression, etc.

In ANTLR4 this is implemented by the simple "first alt first" approach - and the sooner an expression is evaluated the higher is its precedence. In your `x` rule you listed the `+` sub expression first, hence it has the highest precedence. No wonder you get a parse tree that shows `+` at the lowest level. By making `*` the top operator and `+` second you get the expected outcome, as this parse tree shows:

[image]